# Cannot read POST response body from external api in firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, linkedin-api

I have a cloud function which makes an http POST request to the LinkedIn API in order to retrieve an access token. The problem is that I cannot read the `body` of the response, it's always `undefined`.

Here's the code

```js
exports.linkedinToken = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let url = "https://linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?...REQUIRED_PARAMS...";

    request.post(url, {json: true}, (err, response, body) => {
      if (!!err) { // this is never happening
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
      } else {
        console.log(response.body); // this is always undefined
        console.log(body); // this is always undefined
      }
});
```

If I try the same request with Postman or curl it works perfectly, and I cannot really understand why.

Before this request, I made another GET request to the linkedin API and it works normally. Maybe there's a problem with POST requests.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing headers.

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
  headers: {
    'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'cache-control' : 'no-cache'
  },
  url: url
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: I solved it using axios instead of request. Maybe the reason is that axios in including these headers that were missing in request. I'll try and then I'll check this answer as correct. Thanks